# Bootstrap breakpoints

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been working with bootstrap for a few years now and I've never had the issue I'm currently having. Right now I'm having an issue with the 768px breakpoint not collapsing the navbar like it should. I'm using BS 3.3.5 minified css. It will collapse the navbar at 767px. I've started my own queries but it's bootstrap that's not allowing the navbar to collapse. I promise I know what I'm doing. But this is the first time the BS breakpoints aren't working. I looked at the unminified files and it's saying the break point is 767px but I don't understand why it would have changed from 768px in BS 3.3.2. When I put it to 767px all my columns are pulling the -xs instead of -sm but at 768px it pulls the right column size but it's not collapsing the navbar.

my navigation.

```
<div id="main-nav">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
       <div class="container-fluid">
       <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
          </div><!-- end of navbar header -->

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse container" id="main-navbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sausage</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Pork</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Beef</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Country Store</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>                                
              </ul>

           </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
       </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
   </nav>
</div><!-- end of main-nav -->
```

Comment: You use Bootstrap for years and you add `container` class to `#main-navbar`? :)

Comment: i was trying something and forgot to delete.

Comment: but thank you so much for helping with my problem

Comment: uhm.. the breakpoint SHOULD be at 767 and not at 768, cause most of the Tablets have a width of 768px. so the nav should collapse AFTER 768 and not AT 768. normal behaviour. thats why the breakpoint is written in the media query for "min-width: 768px". cause at the minimum width of 768 the nav would be in desktop-mode.